# Unblock window.open pop-up?

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, popup

Due to the limitations of a ***really*** clunky CMS, I am unable to use

```
target="_blank"
```

to open links in new windows. So I'm thinking that my only real solution is to point the link at an intermediary page that opens a new window and then redirects the current window back to the originating page... so something like this:

```
window.open ("http://www.NewPage.com/");
window.location = "http://www.OldPage.com/";
```

Of course, most browsers will block the window.open method... so what are my options? Surely there's some clever Javascript trickery to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

No options.  You can't do it, and for good reason.

Browsers will only allow `window.open()` to work when the code that calls it is handling an event like "click". In that circumstance, the browser assumes that the page provides a clickable element and that the user knows there'll be a popup. If a page just calls `window.open()` for a new window from some context like straight script code, or in a "ready" or "load" event handler, or an XMLHttpRequest callback, then the browser assumes the popup may be something obnoxious.

Some browsers allow the **user** to relax those rules, but your code can't force that.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably just inject an iframe on the page and position it over everything, but I would really not recommend this.

The browser will be in control of whether the `window.open` is allowed or not at the end of the day so I wouldn't bother trying to find a solution.